# Sqlite redefine SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to change limit of sql length in sqlite DB, using c# connection.
Can someone help me, pls?

Here is the sqlitecommand:

json string is a very big one.

```
try
{
     string sql = "INSERT INTO SIP_JSON (sip_code, json) VALUES (" + nextSipCode 
          + ",'" + json + "')";
     connection.Open();
     SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     throw new Exception(Exceptions.GATEWAYDB_INSESRTSIPJSON_EXCEPTION, e);
}
finally
{
      connection.Close();
}
```

Exception Is:out of memory

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: The error message for exceeding that limit would be "statement too long". What *is* the length of that JSON? Why aren't you using an SQL parameter?

Comment: All the above, plus [from section 3 of this SQLite documentation page](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) **(a)** You can only **_lower_** this value at run-time (i.e. in the connection string) -- you'd need to recompile SQLite to raise it; and **(b)** You shouldn't do this anyway -- use prepared statements and binding.

Comment: Thanks TripeHound, Can you pls explain wat should I do step by step? What should I write in the connection string? have an example?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but there will be examples of parameterised queries all over SO and the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks TripeHound, I change my query to use prepared statements.

```
   try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SIP_JSON (sip_code, json) VALUES (?,?)";
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("sip_code",nextSipCode));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("json", json));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(Exceptions.GATEWAYDB_INSESRTSIPJSON_EXCEPTION, e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Comment: that is the solution!